# How to create Stepper Progress for steps and substeps using chakra UI

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, frontend, chakra-ui

Need to create a stepper based on landing the page. If i land on business page the progress should match the height of the business. next if i land on the primary-contact page then there should be a tick mark in the business sub step and currently am in the primary contact hence it should be active,

```
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vv3aX.png)
import {
  Box,
  Divider,
  Flex,
  Progress,
  Step,
  StepDescription,
  StepIcon,
  StepIndicator,
  StepNumber,
  StepSeparator,
  StepStatus,
  StepTitle,
  Stepper,
  Text,
  useSteps,
} from '@chakra-ui/react';
import React from 'react';

interface StepperProps {
  subText?: string;
}
export const steps = [
  {
    label: 'Customer Details',
    active: true,
    completed: false,
    subSteps: [
      { label: 'Business Information', active: true, url: '/', completed: false },
      { label: 'Primary Contact', active: false, url: '/primary-contact', completed: false },
      { label: 'Offer Type', active: false, url: '/tradefull-solutions', completed: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Supporting Documents',
    active: false,
    completed: false,
    subSteps: [
      { label: 'Documents Upload', active: false, completed: false },
      { label: 'Additional Assets', active: false, completed: false },
      { label: 'Notes', active: false, completed: false },
    ],
  },
  {
    label: 'Review & Submit',
    active: false,
    completed: false,
  },
];
function Steppers({ subText }: StepperProps) {
  const { activeStep, setActiveStep } = useSteps({
    index: 0,
    count: steps.length,
  });

  const max = steps.length - 1;
  const progressPercent = (activeStep / max) * 100;

  const setHeight = () => {
    switch (subText) {
      case 'business':
        return '20%';
      case 'contact':
        return '40%';
      case 'tradefull':
        return '60%';
    }
  };

  return (
    <Box position="relative">
      <Stepper p="0 12px" mt={4} size="xs" index={activeStep} orientation="vertical" gap="0">
        {steps.map((step, index) => (
          <Step key={index} onClick={() => setActiveStep(index)}>
            <StepIndicator>
              <StepStatus complete={<StepIcon />} />
            </StepIndicator>

            <Box flexShrink="0" mb={2}>
              <Text fontSize="md" fontWeight="medium" color="BaseClr.Primary" mt={0} mb={0} pb="3">
                {step.label}
              </Text>

              {step.subSteps &&
                step.subSteps.map((sub, index) => (
                  <Flex gap={2}>
                    <Text mb={0} fontSize="sm" fontWeight="regular" pb="3">
                      {sub.label}
                    </Text>
                  </Flex>
                ))}
            </Box>
          </Step>
        ))}
      </Stepper>
      <StepSeparator />
    </Box>
  );
}

export default Steppers;
```

I tried creating a separate Box component assigning height and so on

Answer (score 0):

I think for this statement you have to make another stepper inside the parent stepper, that is, nest steppers and then do their configuration instead.